# VBScript helper: getting focus on app

Tags: vbscript

Within a frontend (feel), I need to call a batch file which will close the FE (necessary to prevent it from crashing), do some work and call the FE again.

Anyway, when the FE will be called again, it won't have focus for user input.

At this point, I wrote a VBScript, to put at the end of the batch file, after the FE is called, in order to get focus back on it:

```
Dim bWindowFound
Dim WShell

Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do
    bWindowFound = WShell.AppActivate("Feel")

    If (bWindowFound = -1) Then
        WShell.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
    Else
        WScript.Sleep 1000
    End If
Loop Until bWindowFound = -1

'WScript.Echo "Feel found, quitting ... "

Set WShell = Nothing
WScript.Quit(0)
```

What happens is that the feel window will blink in the application bar but it won't come in front of all the others (so no input can be provided).

The only solution would be to uncomment the following line at the end of the script:

```
WScript.Echo "Feel found, quitting ... "
```

This way it will work: I'll quickly see a pop up window saying "Feel found, quitting ... " and the feel window will come in front of all the others with focus on it.

Unfortunately this is not feasible since I don't want to see any window and, above all, I don't want to have to close it manually!

Comment: Explain what a batch file has to do with this. Your question appears to be with respect to a front end and vbscript.

Comment: Sure, this is what happens:

 - FE is called to select an item
 - after confirming the selection the FE calls a script (batch)
 - the script 'closes' the FE and launches another app
 - after this app finishes, the script starts the FE again

The issue, as I said, it's that the FE comes back not in plain focus (key presses won't go there) and, as such, I wrote a VB script to give it focus back (I didn't find any other way to do the same simply using windows batch commands).

Cheers.

Comment: Is your problem the batch file which you have not posted? If not just remove the irrelevant batch file tag and allow only those with vbscript knowledge to deal with your vbscript problem.

Comment: As I said, the batch file does nothing fancy: it stops the FE, call a program changing something in the graphics card, starts an application and waits for it to stop. After that the FE is called again and vb script should shift focus back on it.